# Parsing timer with php

Tags: php, datetime

I am trying to parse a timer string value in the following format: '01:40.911'

```
DateTime::createFromFormat('i:s.v','01:40.91');
```

but i get false in return value, the issue is related to the milliseconds, when i am generating date time with the same format it looks the same. e.g:

```
$d = new DateTime('now');

var_dump($d->format('i:s.v'));
```

will result in: 58:42.001

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: could be a php version issue https://3v4l.org/NnaHD

Comment: yes, it is.thanks!

Comment: `v` is new for `createFromFormat()` as of PHP 7.3. You can use `u` or `s`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question has already been answered in the comments.

Here are some variants to parse strings like '01:40.911'.

```
$strTime =  '01:40.911';
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');

//PHP >= 7.3
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('i:s.v',$strTime);
var_export($dt);

//PHP >= 5.4.30
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('i:s.u',$strTime);
var_export($dt);

$dt = date_create('00:'.$strTime);
var_export($dt);
```

Output:

```
DateTime::__set_state(array(
   'date' => '2020-04-17 00:01:40.911000',
   'timezone_type' => 3,
   'timezone' => 'Europe/Berlin',
))
DateTime::__set_state(array(
   'date' => '2020-04-17 00:01:40.911000',
   'timezone_type' => 3,
   'timezone' => 'Europe/Berlin',
))
DateTime::__set_state(array(
   'date' => '2020-04-17 00:01:40.911000',
   'timezone_type' => 3,
   'timezone' => 'Europe/Berlin',
))
```